# WSO2 Registry and Apache Synapse Integration

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse

I'm a beginer of SOA ,and I want to know some info of integrating the WSO2 Registry and Apache Synapse.Just like how to publish services through the Synapse to the Registry and get services through the Synapse from the Registry .Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer WS-Discovery functionality in below links.

http://wso2.com/blogs/architecture/2011/09/loosen-up-with-ws-discovery/

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/WS-Discovery

Further look in the below links on how to integrate WSO2 ESB and WSO2 Reg on various ways.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Storing+Various+WSO2+Enterprise+Service+Bus+Configurations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a complete configure samples of this? Thank you.

Comment: These links you will find useful.http://manisha-eleperuma.blogspot.com/2011/09/dynamic-ws-discovery-of-wso2-esb.html and http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2012/07/wso2-esb-proxy-from-registry.html